# code assistance inside included file for a variable defined outside

Tags: php, include, aptana, code-assist

Let's say I create an object in `index.php` and save the reference in the variable `$obj`.
Later in `index.php` I include/require a file `req.php` where I want to use a method of the object.

Is there a way to make Aptana 3.0.4 show me the available methods of the object when I type `$obj->` inside `req.php`?

I.e. Aptana should recognize that the variable `$obj` is already defined higher in the file hierarchy and that it holds a reference to an object.

Comment: Avoid global variables. Pass values as method/function arguments instead.

Answer (score 0):

May be it helps if you add comment before the first var using

```
/* @var YOUR_CLASS */
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax in version 3.0.4 is like that:

```
/**
 * @var Foobar 
 */ 
$obj; // You have to call the variable here (redundant, I know)
$obj-> // will code assist the FooBar functions.
```

Since this is not that great of a syntax, I'm working on having additional support, like with the PDT special @var syntax:

```
/* @var $obj Foobar */
$obj-> // will code assist the FooBar functions.
```

Both should be supported in the Studio's next release.

Hope that helps